# How to find out if your webcam and LED have been hardwired or not

Tags: malware, hardware

In these days webcam and LED in some laptops are interlocked either on a firmware base or a hardware base. Is there any possibility to determine whether or not the LED connection to the webcam is hardware based or firmware based? If it's hardware based then malware can't disable it.

I want to find out for Dell Inspiron 15 3521.

Comment: I'm not sure but I guess could be software based. On my phone I tested making a lab with a trojan and I hijack my phone's webcam without enabling the LED

Comment: How does phone have led on cam

Comment: Yes, is a Google Nexus 5 and if you enable the webcam the LED is lighted on... but with the trojan the LED is still off. You can check the LED here: http://www.notebookcheck.org/fileadmin/Notebooks/Google/Nexus_6P/Nexus_6P_LED.jpg

Comment: Ok but what about laptops

Comment: Trojaning my virtual Windows 7 The laptop's LED was enabled... so not sure if it depends of firmware or why is different. That's because I don't have an answer for you. Sorry.

Comment: @sweetpunk I'm curious: what was the result? Is the led hardwired on your Dell?

Comment: it didnt turn on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are running linux

```
uvcdynctrl -c
```

May show LED

if so

```
LED_STATE: 0=Always-off, 1=Always-on, 2=Always-blink, 3=Auto on
```

then

```
 uvcdynctrl -d CAMERA_NAME -s 'LED1 Mode' 1
```

Should turn it on